# Magento 2.3 How to change the order of customer account form fields with custom module?

Tags: magento2, customer, forms

I created the module name "Name_Module", Now I want to change the order (position) to **" create customer account form fields "**. How could I achieve this functionality?

Also, need to check if the module is enabled then change the order(position).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to change in it?

Comment: need to change the position of the fields.

Comment: Customer Registration Form Or Customer Account Information Form ??

Comment: Customer Registration form

Comment: You will need to override template file of: module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml.

Comment: <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">

    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="name/module/enabled">

        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">CompanyName_Moduelname::form.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>

Comment: it will happen if the module is enabled from system-config, how it check it?

Comment: This will match your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237179/magento-2-i-want-to-add-ifconfig-in-override-block-xml

Comment: @dhairya do i need to add code for override for form in default.xml or customer_account_create.xml ?

Comment: @UtsavGupta customer_account_create.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override template file of:

> module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

Create a layout file:

> CompanyName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>                  
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" ifconfig="section/group/enable>
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">CompanyName_ModuleName::form/register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>     
    </body> 
</page>
```

Template File Path:

> CompanyName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

Comment: @UtsavGupta If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.